# Get text based on xml tag title

Tags: python, xml, tags

**Set-up**

I'm new to xml and ubl xml.

Trying to read the following .xml invoice into Python using ElementTree.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2&#xA;http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd">
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns010:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol4a:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.simplerinvoicing.org:si:si-ubl:ver1.1.x</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:profile:bii04:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>
  <cbc:ID>201909638</cbc:ID>
  <cbc:IssueDate>2019-11-01</cbc:IssueDate>
  <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listAgencyID="6" listID="UNCL1001">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
  <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode listAgencyID="6" listID="ISO 4217 Alpha">EUR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
  <cac:OrderReference>
  # other stuff
</Invoice>
```

If I run `root[4].text`, I get the text at the `IssueDate` tag returned in a string, i.e. `'2019-11-01'`.

---

**Issue**

I'd like to obtain the text based on the tag's title.

- `root.find('IssueDate').text`
- `root.find('cbc:IssueDate').text`

give `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`.

---

**Question**

How can I get the text based on the tag title `IssueDate`?

More generally, how do I get the text of any tag based on the tag's title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET   

xml_string="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2&#xA;http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd">
      <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
      <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns010:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol4a:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.simplerinvoicing.org:si:si-ubl:ver1.1.x</cbc:CustomizationID>
      <cbc:ProfileID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:profile:bii04:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>
      <cbc:ID>201909638</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:IssueDate>2019-11-01</cbc:IssueDate>
      <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listAgencyID="6" listID="UNCL1001">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
      <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode listAgencyID="6" listID="ISO 4217 Alpha">EUR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
      <cac:OrderReference>ABC</cac:OrderReference>
    </Invoice>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
```

here I have used string for the input, you also use XML file for it.
Now to get text-based on tag's title First, you need to know what is a name of the tag.

```
for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

Output:

```
{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}UBLVersionID {}
{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}CustomizationID {}
{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}ProfileID {}
{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}ID {}
{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}IssueDate {}
{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}InvoiceTypeCode {'listAgencyID': '6', 'listID': 'UNCL1001'}
{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}DocumentCurrencyCode {'listAgencyID': '6', 'listID': 'ISO 4217 Alpha'}
{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2}OrderReference {}
```

you can see that your logic was right for finding text but you have provided the wrong title. Due to Invoice attributes, here we cannot directly find text using ***'IssueDate'***
or ***'cbc:IssueDate'***

if you have used

```
root.find("{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}IssueDate").text
```

Output:

```
'2019-11-01'
```

Here ***"urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"*** is added in front of IssueDate because of ***cbc*** in tag's title. If it was not than ***"urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"*** would be added in front.

I hope this answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeautifulSoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS4

xml_test = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2&#xA;http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd">
      <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
      <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns010:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol4a:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.simplerinvoicing.org:si:si-ubl:ver1.1.x</cbc:CustomizationID>
      <cbc:ProfileID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:profile:bii04:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>
      <cbc:ID>201909638</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:IssueDate>2019-11-01</cbc:IssueDate>
      <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listAgencyID="6" listID="UNCL1001">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
      <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode listAgencyID="6" listID="ISO 4217 Alpha">EUR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
      <cac:OrderReference>ABC</cac:OrderReference>
    </Invoice>"""

soup = BS4(xml_test)

tag = soup.find("cbc:issuedate")

print(tag.text)
```

The result will be

```
2019-11-01
```

If you have many `issue dates` you can use

```
tags = soup.findAll("cbc:issuedate")
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.text)
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimplifiedDoc, too.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2&#xA;http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd">
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns010:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol4a:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.simplerinvoicing.org:si:si-ubl:ver1.1.x</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:profile:bii04:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>
  <cbc:ID>201909638</cbc:ID>
  <cbc:IssueDate>2019-11-01</cbc:IssueDate>
  <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listAgencyID="6" listID="UNCL1001">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
  <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode listAgencyID="6" listID="ISO 4217 Alpha">EUR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
  <cac:OrderReference>
  # other stuff
</Invoice>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.getElementByTag('cbc:IssueDate').text) # get one
lst = doc.getElementByTag('Invoice').getChildren() # get all
for item in lst:
  print (item.tag,item.text)
```